# Estimates maximum of linear equation division

Tags: linear-algebra, parameter-estimation

I have a really hard and confusing problem like below:

$f(A,B)=\frac{k_{2_{A_2}}*k_{2_{A_2}}*A_2+k_{1_{B_2}}*k_{2_{B_2}}*B_2}{k_{1_{A_1}}*k_{2_{A_1}}*A_1+k_{1_{B_1}}*k_{2_{B_1}}*B_1}$

Then I define like this:

$f_A = \frac{k_{1_{A_2}}}{k_{1_{A_1}}} * \frac{k_{2_{A_2}}}{k_{2_{A_1}}} * \frac{A_2}{A_1}$

$f_B = \frac{k_{1_{B_2}}}{k_{1_{B_1}}} * \frac{k_{2_{B_2}}}{k_{2_{B_1}}} * \frac{B_2}{B_1}$

Then $f(A,B)$ can be simplified as:

$f(A,B)=\frac{f_A*k_{1_{A_1}}*k_{2_{A_1}}*A_1+f_B*k_{1_{B_1}}*k_{2_{B_1}}*B_1}{k_{1_{A_1}}*k_{2_{A_1}}*A_1+k_{1_{B_1}}*k_{2_{B_1}}*B_1}$

What I have are:

1. The value of $A_1$ and $B_1$
2. $\frac{A_2}{A_1}$ and $\frac{B_2}{B_1}$
3. The ratio of $k_1$ is between 0 and 1
4. The ratio of $k_2$ is unknown but I think it can be assumed that the maximum of $k_2$ is equal to the ratio of $\frac{A_2}{A_1}$ and $\frac{B_2}{B_1}$

Is it possible to estimate the maximum value of $f(x)$ with regard to $f_A$ and $f_B$ (a function with only $f_A$ and $f_B$ as parameter)?

If not possible, what assumption do I need to make so that it is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably $f_A$ and $f_B$ are functions of $x$.  If the $k$s, $A_1, B_1$ are positive, then increasing $f_A$ and $f_B$ will increase $f$, so there will be no maximum unless you use the functional form of $f_A, f_B$

Comment: I have edited the equation because I forget to add some detail before. Can you give your suggestion with the new equation?

Comment: What is varying with $x$?  Something must if $f$ is going to depend on $x$. It is still true that if the $A$s, $B$s, and $k$s are positive you want $f_A$ and $f_B$ to be maximized.

Comment: So, I add the possible maximum value of k1 and k2.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no x in the function. The function is just consist of A and B. My mistake. I automatically use f(x) for function name. I will edit it.

Comment: I still don't know what you are varying.  If you want to vary the values of $f_A,f_B$, you must vary some of the things that go into them. You can certainly take $\frac {df}{df_A}$ and if everything is positive it will be positive.  That says there is no maximum with $f_A$

Comment: What I want to vary is $k_1$ and $k_2$. That is the parameter that I want to estimate.

Comment: With the assumption, I think that $f_A$ has maximum which is 
${\frac{A_2}{A_1}}^2$